# Figuring out Linux memory usage

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

I've got a bit weird Linux memory usage I'm trying to figure out.

I've got 2 processes: `nxtcapture` & `nxtexport`. None of these processes really allocate much memory however they both `mmap` a 1 TB file each. **`nxtexport` has no heap allocations** (apart from during startup). `nxtcapture` writes sequentially to the file and `nxtexport` reads sequentially. Since `nxtexport` reads from the tail of `nxtcapture` I don't really have any read IO.

```
ing992:~# iostat -m
Linux 4.4.52-nxt (ing992)   05/25/17    _x86_64_    (32 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          29.17    1.99    0.96    0.06    0.00   67.82

Device:            tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
loop0             0.02         0.00         0.00          2          0
sdf              16.47         0.06         0.85       4207      61442
sdf1              0.00         0.00         0.00          5          0
sdf2              0.01         0.00         0.00         77          0
sdf3             16.45         0.06         0.85       4115      61442
sdf4              0.00         0.00         0.00          7          0
sde              15.45         0.01         0.85       1032      61442
sde1              0.00         0.00         0.00          5          0
sde2              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
sde3             15.44         0.01         0.85       1017      61442
sde4              0.00         0.00         0.00          7          0
sdb              43.08         0.00        15.72         22    1136368
sda              43.07         0.00        15.72         21    1136406
sdc              43.42         0.04        15.72       2711    1136332
sdd              43.07         0.00        15.72         20    1136301
md127             0.01         0.00         0.00         77          0
md126            23.77         0.07         0.85       5132      61145
```

This all great. However, looking at the memory usage I can see the following:

[image]

Which shows that more than half of my memory is unavailable?! How is this possible? I understand that `mmap` will keep pages cached. But shouldn't such (non-dirty) pages be counted as available? What's going on here? How can I debug this?

[image]

```
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32020      31608        412        221         13       9655
-/+ buffers/cache:      21939      10081
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: Why do you think clean pages should be counted as available? This makes no sense.

Comment: Because they can be reclaimed?

Comment: Is there a way I can force GC of all clean pages just to verify that everything is ok?

Comment: No, it can not be "reclaimed". It can be taken away from the process that maps it. There is nothing that can guarantee you that process won't need to use it again a nanosecond after you appropriate it. Garbage can be reclaimed. Garbage is something no one will be using in the future.

Comment: If you want a page to become available, unmap it.

Comment: I want to avoid unmapping it since that adds a lot of complexity to a process running 24/7.

Is there a way I can see how many of the used pages are clean and can be stolen/reclaimed by another process when free memory becomes scarce?

Comment: `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` should hint to the os that the pages can be reclaimed? i.e. " pages in the given range can be aggressively read ahead, and *may be freed* soon after they are accessed." (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html)

Comment: Or maybe `MADV_DONTNEED` could help?

Comment: I didn't know about madvice. Looks like either one could help.